# iOS External Accessories Framework with Bluetooth High-BT Using MFI

Tags: ios, iphone, core-bluetooth, external-accessory

I am working on iOS External Accessories Framework, my question is can External Accessories Framework, is capable to detecting nearby bluetooth devices, or i have to go with CoreBluetooth to do the Scanning for BT.

Also refer if you have any tutorial related to iOS External Accessories Framework, or similar

Thank you!!!

Comment: Is your device a Bluetooth Low Energy/Bluetooth 4.0 device or a Bluetooth 2.1/3.0 device? If it is the former then you will use Core Bluetooth, if the latter then you need to use external accessory framework via the MFi program

Comment: Its a Bluetooth 4.0, still i have to use Core-bluetooth to scan nearby device, or the scanning and paring will be done by External Accessory Framework itself. (Yes i am using MFI program)

Comment: If it is BT4.0 then you need to use CoreBluetooth.  See the question on BLE in the MFi FAQ https://mfi.apple.com/MFiWeb/getFAQ.action#4-2

Comment: Yes i have already done with the above link, i just want to know will External Accessories Framework will do the Scanning, Paring of the from the list of devices (though it do the communication part), And ya we are using MFI, were we have our custom protocols communicating with iOS App using EAFramework.

Comment: No, if it is BLE then external accessory framework does not get involved.  You need to discover your peripheral using CBCentralManager, display a list if required, obtain a selected peripheral and initiate a connection. Here is an example of scanning, selecting & connecting to a BLE peripheral https://github.com/paulw11/BTBackground

Comment: Thanks bro!!! but "EA.framework" alone is capable of doing the bluetooth job like Scanning, Paring ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65682/discussion-between-paulw11-and-master-tushar).